# splitting headers array in curl response

Tags: php, curl

```
$headers = array(
                    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
                    "Accept: text/xml",
                    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                    "Pragma: no-cache",
                    "SOAPAction: http://ctitechnology.com/UpsertEntity",
                    "Content-length: ".strlen($soap_request),
                );


$soap_do = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL, "http://66.7.227.4/tio_ws/ScreeningPartnerWS.asmx");
        curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $soap_request); // the SOAP request
        curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

        $result = curl_exec($soap_do);


    print "Response:\n";
    print($result);
    print "\n";

    if($result === false) {
            $error = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($soap_do);
            curl_close($soap_do);
            print $error;
    } else {

            $xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
            print_r($xml);
            print "\n";
```

I am trying to split the header when it comes back in the response (I need to keep the headers, turning CURLOPT_HEADER to false would do it but I need to keep the response's header intact). At the moment, am not able to parse the xml because the header is included. Any wisdom would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any reason you're not using [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php)?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP/1.1 specifies that any message body should come after “[an empty line (i.e., a line with nothing preceding the CRLF) indicating the end of the header fields](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.1)”

Your question has been [answered already here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8756268/1737136).